# Flickering/Alternating Black Screen on External Monitor

Tags: graphics-card, windows-11, external-display

**Edit 1/16/2023:**
I managed to do some digging/additional troubleshooting on the issue and discovered it is actually OS-based, rather than hardware-based; it appears some sort of system file/process — whatever deals with the desktop/GUI — is corrupted and buggy, which is causing the desktop to "flicker."  I've attached to this post some pictures and videos that should better illustrate the problem, and I included below a list of everything I've tried to resolve the issue.  I've basically tried everything I can think of short of doing a clean reinstall, and I'd rather not resort to that just yet, so if anyone has any other suggestions I'd appreciate it.

Troubleshooting done so far:

- Using bootable USB, ran Windows 11 PE and exhausted all of the recovery options available, including Startup Repair, uninstalling updates, using CMD to run SFC and DISM, and Resetting the PC.
- Booted into friend's computer, inserted the Windows 11 bootable USB, and ran setup.exe to try doing an in-place "upgrade" to Windows 11 (was an option I found online as an alternative to resetting the PC in Windows PE, and would do a reinstall without deleting her files).  Failed with some generic error.
- Restarted the File Explorer process in Task Manager
- Attempted to clear the File Explorer cache in Control Panel (wouldn't load)
- Run SFC and DISM again; failed as Windows wouldn't let us use elevated privileges in PS.

Images/Videos:

[Video 1: Desktop "Flickering"](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTtLmEAz0fOHULsqWmtROwVCuT1F902qbWGHFxaS9vBJKPsHWl5n8yHlBwLOaSaBFpF3L_e1wvGDpp3/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=60000)

[Video 2: Unable to open File Explorer Options in Control Panel and delete cache](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vT976j7dd0aWPqx55LLMknVkrYm-NoVpz0Qg-fTH7H9grix-IgZAibInaAORDrz-XehSHeXKAv0wf7D/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=60000)

[Image 1: Unable to launch Windows Settings, as "Package Repository is Corrupted"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYZIa.jpg)

[Image 2: File Explorer options (top of window) are greyed out when they shouldn't be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00kNq.jpg)

---

**Original Post:**

Troubleshooting a friend’s custom-built gaming rig from Best Buy; she came to me saying how the screen will alternate between a black screen and her desktop background (just the background, no icons, taskbar, or anything else) every five seconds or so after being powered on (issue only happens once the OS loads), and it doesn’t accept any user input. She explained how the issue started after she wiped out the dusty interior with a cleaning cloth; my initial assumption was ESD damage but I have no way to credibly verify that and would rather not chalk it up to that just yet.

She has a CyberPower PC (she mentioned something about it being a Gamer Master Gaming Desktop; not sure what that means) with an AMD Ryzen 7 5700X running Windows 11; we’re working on getting the make/model of the graphics card but she’s saying it’s not showing up anywhere on her receipt or in her emails from Best Buy.

The monitor works fine when connected to one of her sister’s laptops, which indicates the issue is isolated to the computer itself.  I started troubleshooting by disconnecting everything, doing a flea power reset, blowing out any excess dust, and reseating the graphics card; when that didn’t work, I booted into safe mode, which gave us some progress (ie. the sign in screen popped up) but when we signed in the monitor started spazzing out and flickering really fast, and while it technically accepted user input, it was really hard to do anything.

Doing a quick Google search seems to point to it being some sort of driver issue, but I’m not entirely sure how to go about addressing that without completely wiping the computer, as we’re unable to log into her user with or without safe mode; only other thing that comes to mind would be to flash the BIOS.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: First thing I'd try would be booting another OS from USB,e.g., Linux Live or Hiren's Boot CD. If that works, then the issue is with OS or drive, **not** hardware. No need to install the OS, just test if it boots and displays.

Comment: I don't see how a problem that appeared after a cleaning spree could be related to the driver.

Comment: @harrymc I mentioned the cleaning spree because I'm not 100% sure yet what caused the issue; I'm suspecting/hoping it's a driver issue, but it seemed odd to me that the behavior started happening right after she wiped out the interior which I'm assuming could have caused ESD.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you!  I'll give it a shot and let you all know how it works.